# AntiSamy adds new line character "\n"

Tags: java, security, xss, owasp, antisamy

After cleaning the dirty input , Antisamy prepends new line character `"\n"` and replaces `" "` space with `"\n"`.
I am using antisamy 1.5.3 jar.

For e.g.: below is the output after cleaning json

```
"\n{\"instanceId\":\"54117\",\"chatTime\":\"11:30\nAM\"}
```

here

`11:30\nAM`..this was `11:30 AM`

Comment: That's a weird use case. AntiSamy is not meant for escaping JSON. If you are outputting JSON as a part of HTML, you could consider other options for escaping it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked after modifying formatOutput to false
and adding preserveSpace to true in policy file